# .htaccess RewriteRule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want

```
http://mysite.com/?p=47&preview=true
```

to be rewritten to

```
http://mysite.hostingcompany.com/?p=47&preview=true
```

But all other requests to http://mysite.com/ to act normally

My .htaccess looks like this:

```
RewriteCond ^mysite.com\/?p=(.*)\&preview=true$
RewriteRule ^mysite.hostingcompany.com/?p=$1&preview=true$ [L]
```

But it's not matching. I must be butchering my regular expression but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RewriteCond` matches against a variable like `%{HTTP_HOST}` or `%{QUERY_STRING}`. In your case, you can make use of both of them:

```
# If the requested host is mysite.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite\.com$
# And the query string matches
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} p=(\d+)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} preview=true
# Redirect it, appending the querystring as is
RewriteRule (.*) http://mysite.hostingcompany.com/$1 [L,R,QSA]
```

Comment: QSA isn't required since the query string isn't being touched.

Comment: PERFECT. I keep forgetting that conditions are sequential and I don't have to do in one move. Thanks a million.

Comment: There's a checkbox next to this answer.  If you click it, it will mark this answer as correct.